# raster detecting and/or projecting crs incorrectly (LCC to WGS84)

Tags: raster, projection, netcdf

I have ncdf files that I read in using the raster function `brick`. My example / explanation focuses on one layer in the brick

Data available here (too large for tinyupload): https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f21973282c3f9aa4153e9b29ab26227f20190612111133/d1f6b123571e8f7f25cdc633e27c3fa220190612111133/7bd6ec

```
> rt <- brick("mrros/mrros_EUR-11_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_rcp85_r1i1p1_CNRM-ALADIN63_v2_mon_200601-201012.nc", 
+             varname = "mrros")[[1]] 
> rt
class      : RasterLayer 
band       : 1  (of  60  bands)
dimensions : 453, 453, 205209  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 12.5, 12.5  (x, y)
extent     : -6.25, 5656.25, -6.25, 5656.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_0=49.5 +lat_1=49.5 +lon_0=10.5 +ellps=WGS84 +lat_2=45 
source     : C:/Users/coding/Desktop/Files/mrros/mrros_EUR-11_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_rcp85_r1i1p1_CNRM-ALADIN63_v2_mon_200601-201012.nc 
names      : X2006.01.16 
z-value    : 2006-01-16 
zvar       : mrros 

> 
> plot(rt)
>
```

[image]

The raster brick automatically detects the crs of the data. The only thing that looks like it might be missing is the units of the data (data in 12.5 km intervals)

```
> crs(rt)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=lcc +lat_0=49.5 +lat_1=49.5 +lon_0=10.5 +ellps=WGS84 +lat_2=45 
> crs(rt) = paste0(crs(rt), "+units=km")
> crs(rt)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=lcc +lat_0=49.5 +lat_1=49.5 +lon_0=10.5 +ellps=WGS84 +lat_2=45+units=km
```

I want to change the projection into WGS84

```
> rtPr <- projectRaster(rt, crs = CRS("+init=EPSG:4326")) 
> rtPr %>% plot
```

[image]

These units are clearly not WGS84, Europe does not have a longitudinal range of .12 degrees (or a latitudinal range of .5 degrees)!

Is anyone able to advise on why the `projectRaster` does not return the data on the appropriate grid? I presume it has something to do with the assumption of the input crs, but I have no idea what to change it to as these are the values I would have specified if I had done it manually!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps a bit

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(f, var="mrros")
print(r)
```

This shows

```
#char Lambert_Conformal[]   
#  latitude_of_projection_origin: 49.5
#  standard_parallel: 49.5
#  longitude_of_central_meridian: 10.5
#  grid_mapping_name: lambert_conformal_conic
```

The unit is stored elsewhere, and that is not picked up by raster

```
#dimensions
#  units: km
```

The raster package creates this proj.4 string

```
x <- "+proj=lcc +lat_0=49.5 +lat_1=49.5 +lon_0=10.5"
```

(r)gdal changes it (I do not know why it adds "lat_2")

```
CRS(x)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=lcc +lat_0=49.5 +lat_1=49.5 +lon_0=10.5 +ellps=WGS84 +lat_2=45
```

The below changes gets it close. But I am just guessing a bit. Perhaps the problem is that there is also a rotation??

```
crs(r) = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=49.5 +lon_0=-10.5 +ellps=WGS84 +lat_2=49.5 +units=km"
plot( projectRaster(r, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") )
```

It is perhaps best to ask for a standard projection description at the source of the data